# What is the name of the numbers defined by this recursion based on the expansion of exp(1)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, terminology

I was playing around and deduced that for $n$ a whole number  $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{j^n}{j!} = f(n)e$. The integer coefficients $f(n)$ with $f(0)=1$, satisfy the recursion $f(n+1)=\sum_{j=0}^n ($$\begin{matrix}n\\j\end{matrix}$$)f(j)$. The first values $f(1)$ to $f(8)$ are stated on page 13, (Formula 0.248) of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 6'th edition. No name is given for these numbers which grow faster than an exponential function of $n$.

Comment: This is the [Dobinski formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula) for the [Bell numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).